# Open-drain Input mode

Tags: gpio, open-drain

I have a GPIO expander (namely the MAX7317+ from Maxim Intergrated).
The I/O is open-drain.
I want to configure these I/O as Input mode.
Can I just connect them directly to my switch like this so that whenever the switch is pressed, a HIGH signal can be detected (default LOW)?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSgXc3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: "Open-drain" terminology relates to outputs only. There's no such thing as "open-drain" input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datasheet indicates "open-drain **output**, or an overvoltage-protected Schmitt **input**". If you configure the pins as inputs then you will have Schmitt inputs, and you should be able to do as you suggest, however you may want to add some signal debouncing to eliminate switching noise when you activate the switches etc. But in brief, yes you could do that which you suggest.

Comment: I'd suggest to add another 10K resistor just in front of the MAX7317 pin. This prevents a problem if the pin is accidently programmed as an output driven low and the button is pressed.